# New file on my Macbook Pro with odd custom permissions. Have I been hacked?

Tags: security, permission

So today I was looking for something on my MacBook Pro and saw folder called library with the custom permissions.

It seems like it has to permissions, systems (read, write) and everyone no access.

I expanded the permissions so that I could view it. However it seems to have an empty folder inside. The empty folder has the same permissions.

The folder is located in my iCloud > Documents folder and is called Library and the folder inside of it is also Logs.

Additionally I can see that the file was created two days ago.

Moreover, I have all sharing services turned off in my Systems Preferences > Sharing.

There is currently no user profile under the name of systems in System Preferences > Users & Groups.

Why do I have a new file with custom permissions ? Have I been hacked? Is there something I can check to see if there is something wrong going on?

(Also got an email recently saying someone tried to reset a BestBuy password but that my be irrelevant for this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/Library` is where system files are kept - configurations for applications, etc. Generally, unless something is broken, you wouldn't need to access `/Library` for anything. Your main location for your files - the ones you need to access is actually `/Users`. Hence, permissions for System Only are right for `/Library`

I would likewise not be concerned about something that says "Logs" on it. Logging is a useful tool for diagnostics - or to put it another way - to work out what is going on or where something may have gone wrong.

Comment: Okey but way does it look like it suddenly appear? And is empty and Documents?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean - but because when you open Finder, it defaults to your home directory - `/Users/YourName` - you wouldn't see `Library` at all.